# Algebraic independence of solutions

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I'm studying field theory.
When I study the proof of Abel–Ruffini theorem,
I wonder if the following proposition holds.

Proposition

Let

$L_0/K$ be a field extension and $f(x)\in L_0[x]$.
And suppose the set of coefficients of $f(x)$ are algebraically independent over $K$ and $L_1\supset L_0$ is a splitting field　of $f(x)$

Then

the set of solutions of $f(x)$ is algebraically independent over K.

Does this proposition hold?

Answer (score 0):

No, this proposition does not hold.

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}, L_0=\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$, $f(x)=x^2-\pi\in L_0[x]$.

The splitting field $L_1$ of $f(x)$ over $L_0$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\pi})$ and the set of solutions $S$ of f(x) is $\{\pm\sqrt \pi\}$.

Let $h(x_1, x_2)= x_1 +x_2\in \mathbb{Q}[x_1, x_2]$. Since $h(\sqrt{\pi}, -\sqrt{\pi})=0$, S is not algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

The set of coefficients of $f(x)$ is $\{1, -\pi\}$, which is algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ as $\pi$ is not algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.